# How can i update tables from one database to another having a same sql server?

Tags: sql, sql-server, database

I am trying to update a table from one database to another database having a same server. For example: Table1 has a certain columns with values in database_1, in case if my Table1 gets updated with the new values it has to sync the data to the database2.

In short Database1, Table1 has to be copied to Database2 
But complete copyig is not  necessary every time. may updation is sufficient.

database1.Table 1: 1,2,3,4,5
database2.Table 2: 1,2,3

how this 4,5 can be updated in database2 ? 
Thank you.

Comment: 1. You have conflicting tags assigned to your question. 2. You have not provided sufficient information to help you. 3. You have not researched the problem online.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the normal joins to join and update the tables. Like this

```
UPDATE a
SET Name = B.Name
FROM MyDatabase1.dbo.TableA A
inner join MyDatabase2.dbo.TableB B
 ON A.Idd = B.Id
```

Here TableA and TableB are on diffrent Databases on the Same server, So, I'm just giving it as **[DatabaseName].[SchemaName].[TableName]**

Comment: Thank you Jayasurya! That was helpful.